# Cannot see second button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

I'm trying to create a menu on my home screen but I cannot see the second button that I created. I tried `android:layout_below="@+id/score_button"` but it gives warning "invalid layout parameter"

**Here is my xml file**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/score_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="scoreGame"
        android:text="@string/score_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/action_settings" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Something that I've noticed is that whichever button is placed first in the xml file is the one that is displayed when I run the app on my device.

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Try to set android:layout_width="wrap_content"..!!!!

Comment: android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: and set button width to  android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Answer (score 1):

use **RelativeLayout** instead of **LinearLayout**
then you can use `android:layout_below="@+id/score_button"`

and remove  `android:orientation="horizontal"` when using RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout_width to wrap_content:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/score_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="scoreGame"
    android:text="@string/score_button" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/settings_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/action_settings" />
```

Also if you want equal width buttons, give layout_weight:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to both the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/score_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="scoreGame"
        android:text="@string/score_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/action_settings" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Repace your xml code by this code...

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/score_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="scoreGame"
    android:text="@string/score_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/settings_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/action_settings" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

User orientation as Vertical. In linear layout there is no layout_below attribute. Use Relative layout instead.

Answer (score 0):

To force same width for both buttons:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ... />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ... />
```

To use natural buttons width:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ... />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "match_parent" for width, put weight

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/score_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="scoreGame"
        android:text="@string/score_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/action_settings" />
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to show the menu in  horizontal

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/score_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="scoreGame"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/score_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/action_settings" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And if you want to show one blow the other change orientation to Vertical

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Change this **orientation** `horizontal` to `vertical` like below

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the button width and height appropriately and check again .. All the best

Answer (score 0):

The `android:layout_below=""` attribute can only be used with a **Relative Layout**. You have chosen a **Linear Layout**.

Also both the buttons choose the "`match_parent`" for the `android:layout_width` attribute.

Either change "`match_parent`" to "`wrap_content`", otherwise change the `android:orientation` tag of the linear layout to "**vertical**".

Also if you change the layout to relative, it will work.

Comment: Please accept any answer, so that this question is not showed in the unanswered section.